# Custom Mult-Step Form remove next button

Tags: 7, forms

I have built a Multi-Step form using forms example module as a base:

https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example!form_example_wizard.inc/function/form_example_wizard/7

I have a function that takes the user-inputted location on the first form and returns data for presentation on the 2nd form. If no data if returned back from the first form I want to hide the Next button. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this on the second form:

```
if (empty($form_state['values']['location']) {
    $form['next']['#access'] = FALSE
}
```